# Rails 5 - Namespaced folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, nested

I am trying (and not getting very far) to understand how to use namespaced folders in my Rails 5 app.

I have tables in my schema for users, identities and settings.

The associations are:

User

```
has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
has_one :setting, dependent: :destroy
```

Setting

```
belongs_to :user
```

Identity

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have organised my controller folders so that I have app/controllers/users/identities_controller.rb and app/controllers/users/settings_controller.rb

Each of those controllers has this first line:

```
class Users::SettingsController < ApplicationController
class Users::IdentitiesController < ApplicationController
```

I have organised my views folders in a similar way.

I have app/views/users/settings/show.

I don't have views for identities, except for a partial called _authentications.html.erb. Currently that is stored in the app/views/users folder. I'm trying to move it to the app/views/users/settings folder and render it from the app/views/users/settings/show page.

In my routes file I have:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :assign_roles
      resources :identities
      resources :profiles
      resources :settings
    end
```

When I render the authentications partial from the app/views/users show page, I have no errors. Everything works. I am getting stuck because there is something that Im not understanding & I don't know what it is.

I'm trying to move the authentications partial to app/views/users/settings so that I can render it from app/views/users/settings/show.

When I try to do that, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `identities' for nil:NilClass
```

That error references this block of my authentications partial:

```
<% if @user.identities.map(&:provider).include?('linkedin') %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
<% else %>  
    <%= link_to 'Connect your Linkedin account', user_linkedin_omniauth_authorize_path %>
<% end %>
```

I don't understand whether I'm supposed to try to add settings in that if statement somehow? I tried if @setting.user.identities (only as a guess), but it didn't work.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to find a plain english explanation of how to get started with nesting and namespacing.

**Add settings controller**

```
class Users::SettingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_setting, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  after_action :verify_authorized

  def index
    @settings = Setting.all
    authorize @settings
  end

  def show
    # authorize @setting
  end


  def new
    @setting = Setting.new
    authorize @setting

  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @setting = Setting.new(setting_params)
    authorize @setting

    respond_to do |format|
      if @setting.save
        format.html { redirect_to @setting }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @setting }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
   respond_to do |format|
      if @setting.update(setting_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @setting }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @setting }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @setting.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to settings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_setting
      @setting = Setting.find(params[:id])
      authorize @setting
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit( :newsletter )
    end

end
```

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that @user is nil in your partial. Can you share the relevant controller action code?

Comment: @omnikron - which partial do you mean? If I render _authentications.html.erb when it is saved as a file under views/users and render in users/show - everything works. The thing I am trying to change is that i move the authentications partial to save it in the views/users/settings folder and render it in the views/users/settings/show.html.erb. Which controller is relevant in that scenario?

Comment: That controller whose action is rendering the partial. My guess is settings controller.

Comment: I added the settings controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `@user` variable being set in your `show` action, which is why you're getting that `NoMethodError undefined method 'identities' for nil:NilClass`
 error.  `@user` returns `nil` in your partial. You can either set this in the controller with `@user = current_user` (assuming you are using devise) or replace `@user` with `current_user` in your partial.

Having said all of that - is there any particular reason that you want to namespace all of your controllers like this? Just because you have set up a `has_many` or `has_one` relationship between your *models* doesn't necessarily mean that you have to namespace your controllers as well. If you have a good reason to do it then fine; if not then you could consider moving the controllers out of the users namespace.

Comment: Thanks very much. The reason I want the name spaces is that I tried it with everything at the top level and it gets really messy when there isn't any folder organisation. Thanks so much for the explanation.